# .SQLServerException: The stream value is not the specified length

Tags: java, sql, image, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to insert values in inherited tables including image data type

i tried to insert just in parent table there is no errors after that when i tried to insert in both it gave me an sql exception error in provided length 
this is the error
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The stream value is not the specified length. The specified length was 77,896, the actual length is 0.

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("begin transaction insert into employee (JobId,EmpFullName,empuser,emppass,empPhone,empEmail,EmpImage,empGender,empNationality,empAddress) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)commit; insert into Manager (JobId,EmpFullName,empuser,emppass,empPhone,empEmail,EmpImage,empGender,empNationality,empAddress) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
ps.setInt(1, 1);
ps.setString(2,txtFName.getText() );
ps.setString(3,txtUserName.getText());
ps.setString(4,txtPassword.getText());
ps.setString(5,txtPhone.getText());
ps.setString(6,txtEmail.getText());
System.out.println(fin);
ps.setBinaryStream(7,fin,len);

ps.setString(8,gender);
ps.setString(9,cmbNationality.getValue());
ps.setString(10,cmbAddress.getValue());
ps.setInt(11, 1);
ps.setString(12,txtFName.getText() );
ps.setString(13,txtUserName.getText());
ps.setString(14,txtPassword.getText());
ps.setString(15,txtPhone.getText());
ps.setString(16,txtEmail.getText());
System.out.println(fin);
ps.setBinaryStream(17,fin,len);
ps.setString(18,gender);
ps.setString(19,cmbNationality.getValue());
ps.setString(20,cmbAddress.getValue());
```

I expected the values will be inserted in both tables

Comment: Are you sure there are 2 sets of data of size `len` in `fin`? The order of reading the data doesn't seem to be specified making the results of this code unreliable...

Comment: i defined them like this FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
                  int len = (int)file.length();

Comment: After reading the stream once, the stream is depleted... Trying to read the same amount of data again to get the data for the second variable, fails, since there is no more data left in the stream...

Comment: Not for this scenario, just FWIW - double-check that you are actually passing the correct length for your blob value(s). I faced this after a code refactor; the old code had used a `file.length()` as the blob length (where `file` was a `java.io.File`) but the refactor had changed the same variable to a `String` instead - so `file.length()` was still syntactically but returning something completely different! Causing the query to fail